# How to find the "See More Posts from..." button? Selenium - Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Disclaimer: sorry if my explanation is weird. It's my first week learning.

As my first project, I've set out to build a program that counts Instagram posts in a given time frame. Almost everything works, but there is one button standing in my way. (sometimes)

When you open up Instagram with WebDriver, the GDPR notice pops up. This is easy to get rid of since the xpath for this button is always the same. Or less barbaric way:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(ig_link)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Accept"]').click()
```

then, I want to scroll down and during it, get URLs of all posts on the page. As I've already mentioned, on some profiles this works just fine. Yet on others, only few recent posts load up and then you are required to press this pesky "Show More Posts from {instagram_tag}"

[image: The button in action]

My idea was to just brute-force it through `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` but then I found out that on different IG pages, the xpath is different. The button also doesn't have any text directly inside it, so I am not able to use the same approach that I've used with the "Accept" button.

```html
<button class="tCibT qq7_A  z4xUb w5S7h">
  <div class="Igw0E IwRSH eGOV_ _4EzTm lC6p0 HVWg4">
    <div class="_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm         h_zdq  uL8Hv     l4b0S       ">Show More Posts from choco_afro
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

My idea is that I check whether the div element under button includes text "Show More Posts" and then click the button, but I don't know how to do that if even possible. Would anybody be so kind and help me with this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class = "tCibT qq7_A  z4xUb w5S7h"]')

div = btn.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')[1]

if 'Show More Posts' in div.text.strip():
    btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Hopefully, the class of the button is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that, this `xpath` might help you.

```
//button//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Posts')]/../..
```

If each IG page has the same `HTML` design, then this example should help you. 
Solution: Click Show More Posts Button

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button//div[contains(text(), 'Show More Posts')]/../..").click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. From what didn't work for me, I assume though, that there can be slight differences in the HTML, because otherwise, the full xpath would work. From what I remember, there are sometimes more div elements.
Sushils' answer has been already working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to retrieve that button from it's sibling's text by css selector.

```
//div[text()='Show More Posts from choco_afro']/parent::div/parent::button
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally know how to get "up" in xpath :)